# How to generate a positive number from a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I need basically md5 but only with positive numbers. Any good ideas how to achieve this?

Here some pseudo code:

```
console.log(Hash.fromString('I am a string'));
// I need an output something like this: 747485976
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach might be using `String.charCodeAt`, iterating through your string and getting every character's code and then joining them:

```js
var string = 'I am a string';
var charCodes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
 charCodes.push(string.charCodeAt(i));
}
console.log(charCodes.join('')); // 733297109329732115116114105110103
```